# is there any way to skip row inserting in ES while moving data from HIVE to ES?

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, hive

i am trying  to copy data (more then 300 million rows) from hive table to Elasticsearch using this query:-
insert overwrite table TableNameES select * from HiveTableName;

& after inserting some of rows i am getting this exception. i know this is because of different data type of mapping in ES
...

> Caused by: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopInvalidRequest: Found unrecoverable error [xx.xx.xx.xx:9200] returned Bad Request(400) - [MapperParsingException[failed to parse [pctblack.pctblack_raw]]; nested: NumberFormatException[For input string: "(S)"]; ]; Bailing out..**

i want to skip inserting those row which one giving error not only this exception may be other exception.

Comment: for now i replaced "(S)" string with some number.

insert overwrite table TableNameES select regexp_replace(regexp_replace(json_data,'"_id"','"id"'),'"\\(S\\)"','"0.0"')  from HiveTableName;

is it possible to store these type of record somewhere which one giving exception. because there may be a chance of some other exception while inserting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace "(S)" string with some number.

```
insert overwrite table TableNameES select regexp_replace(regexp_replace(json_data,'"_id"','"id"'),'"\(S\)"','"0.0"') from HiveTableName;
```

but this is not a proper solution this will work problem.